# How to remove a tag from a merged question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, merged-questions

I'm still working on eliminating the [close](/questions/tagged/close) tag, but I'm not going to be successful because I've just run across the merged question:

- [JavaScript — Window close on Android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244095/javascript-window-close-on-android-browser).

The question has been merged, so it seems that the tags cannot be edited.  Which means the [close](/questions/tagged/close) tag will survive in perpetuity because of (at least) this question.

What should be done about this?  Ask the Team@StackOverflow.com to deal with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A moderator flag would have sufficed.

Moderator flags are for situations that cannot be handled by the community.  This situation qualifies.

Comment: OK; fair enough.  I wasn't aware of the distinction between merged questions (where I can't make changes) and closed, duplicate, on hold etc questions where I generally can make changes.  I'll flag in future; maybe this will help other people who run across the same thing.

Comment: PS: Thanks for removing the tag from the question.